# How to make an existing directory into an eclipse project

Tags: eclipse

I have a project I am working on. I have decided to try working with it in Eclipse. There is already a directory, under version control where all the code resides. I am having a rather strange problem. I cannot find any way to just start using an existing code directory as an eclipse project. All I can find is how to import existing source into a new project or check out source from version control into a new project. How do I make an existing directory into a project?

My project is a Django web app if it is any help

Answer (score 106, accepted):

In the `New Java Project` wizard, uncheck the checkbox that says `Use default location` and the use the Browse button to find your directory.

Comment: it helped me, as well, just need to open a web perspective after above suggestion.

Answer (score 21):

It is pretty easy to do.  Go to File->New-> Project.  In the Project wizard, choose the type of project you want and then be sure to unclick the 'Use default location` checkbox.  Browse for your folder in the widget that then becomes enabled.  Click finish after that.

Alternatively, you could create a brand new project workspace in a new location.  Then, assuming Java as your project type, you can open up your project properties and add as a source folder your existing directory.  To do this, use the 'Link Source' button on the Java Build Path -> Source tab of your Project Properties dialog.

Comment: When I do this I get the error "D:\___\Projects\foobar overlaps the location of another project: 'foobar'". If I try to import "Existing projects" it says "No projects are found to import" :S Maybe it's because I created the project folder inside the regular workspace folder and now want to turn it into an eclipse project?

Comment: Thanks akf for help. I also have same problem and it worked for me. My project is django web project under version control.

Answer (score 8):

**My Method:**

I clone this file to new project directory , and rename Project-Name to my project name, after that i import new files and directory from Eclips

File Name: `.project` ***( Use Notepad for make this file...select Save as type to `All Files (*.*)` and write file name like: `.project` )***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
    <name>Project-Name</name>
    <comment></comment>
    <projects>
    </projects>
    <buildSpec>
    </buildSpec>
    <natures>
    </natures>
</projectDescription>
```

Comment: I really like this solution, although it doesn't use Eclipse mechanisms. But as Eclipse surprisingly doesn't have an easy mechanism for a simple thing like this, it's a great little trick. Thanks for also providing the little .project file in your answer.

Comment: In my experience the other solutions do not work if your existing root folder is already in the Eclipse workspace, importing a file system failed b/c the root folder is in Eclipses workspace and importing a project failed b/c it is not a project (failure message was 'invalid project description', which is pretty obscure IMO) . adding .project seems to solve the second problem. nice trick

Comment: Similar answer for Netbeans IDE: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5420547/how-to-open-non-netbeans-project-in-netbeans/57694950#57694950

Answer (score 4):

Hope this link answers the original question of this thread.

http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-45.htm

Creating linked resources

Folders and files can be linked to locations in the file system outside of the project's location. These special folders and files are called linked resources.

To create a linked folder:

1. In one of the navigation views, right-click the project or folder where you want to create the linked folder.
2. From the pop-up menu, select command link New > Folder.
3. Specify the name of the folder as it will appear in the workbench. This name can be different from the name of the folder in the file system.
4. Click Advanced.
5. Check Link to alternate location (Linked Folder).
6. Enter a file system path, or click Browse to select a folder in the file system.
7. Click Finish.

Answer (score 3):

Probably not the way most people would go about this, but I like all of my eclipse projects in one place but don't necessarily have my source in my workspace directory.  Maybe there is a built in way to "symlink" in eclipse, but I sometimes end up with the project folder in the workspace, with the "src" symlinked to the actual source directory somewhere totally different.  That's my personal preference anyway.  If you too are on a *nix machine a simple

```
ln -s /path/to/source src
```

will do from your project directory.

Comment: This solution is great; it keeps eclipse's project configuration info out of the real source directory.  Adding new files to the project, etc., still works correctly from within eclipse.

Comment: There is a built-in way to symlink in eclipse.  See @chaben's answer

Answer (score 1):

You know, it is not so simple question. Depending on your project type (jar, web module, ear and so on) different structure and configuration files are used by eclipse. So the first really interesting question is that what is your project type? The basic solution after it to create a new project, and define the directory of your source code as project root. Then you will see what else to change (for example source path settings, classpath and so on). So how does your project look like? Can you proide structure tree of folders?

Comment: I think he wanted only to use an already existing directory in his workspace as a new project, which is a very simple thing and I can't really imagine any real cause why eclipse mystically can't do that without unneeded copy-paste tricks.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Django you should first set up PyDev in Eclipse. You can install it from the market. Then you want to configure the PyDev Python interpreters to find your installation of Django (http://pydev.org/manual_101_interpreter.html). Make sure to provide the explicit path to the Django folder if your Django is not installed in the default location.

Once these things are ready you can select File > New > Other, then select PyDev Django Project from the PyDev sub directory.

Click next and here is the sweet part: Uncheck 'Use default' (as previously stated) and then find your Django project directory. Be sure to select the right project folder (ie: the folder that contains `manage.py`). When you have the right folder selected Eclipse/PyDev will recognize that a project already exists and make mention that it will use those files. Click Finish.

Then there is a DB form that asks about your DB settings. If you already have a `settings.py` file then this seems to make no changes (as it should not). So fill it in or don't. But this is the last step.

Then you should be able to view and use your existing project in Eclipse!

Answer (score 0):

I just created a pom.xml by hand and imported the project as an existing Maven project in Eclipse. It even works for nested projects without problems.

Answer (score -1):

Use "import - existing projects into workspace". This works for my case.

Comment: It actually assumes that you already have Eclipse config files in that folder... so it's actually the exact opposite of what the original poster is asking.  It does not make a copy (by default).

Comment: This makes a separate version of the code, so you get a -1.

Answer (score -1):

Right click on a project -> Properties.
Open project location in explorer, there's a little icon next to path.
Put your folder/file structure in there and refresh the project in eclipse.