# How to open Non-Netbeans project in Netbeans?

Tags: netbeans

When we create a (PHP) project in Netbeans 7, it somehow saves the directory in its own format, and later we can open the project in Netbeans. However, I have a project which I created without Netbeans, now I want to open it with Netbeans, but seems that I can not. When I "Open Project" in Netbeans, and browse to the directory, it does not not recognize the directory. So how can I open a Non-Netbeans project in it?
Thanks.

Comment: Similar question for Eclipse IDE: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170963/how-to-make-an-existing-directory-into-an-eclipse-project

Answer (score 13):

In NetBeans IDE 8.0.1

1. File->New Project
2. Select PHP-> PHP Existing Sources, Click Next
3. Browse Source Folder and Select it
4. Give project a name
5. If you want you can keep a backup in a separate directory, Click Next
6. And select your Server
7. Click Finish

Answer (score 6):

Select "File" > "New Project"

Under "Categories" select "Java"

Under "Projects" select "Java Project with Existing Sources"

You'll then need to tell it which directory contains your sources and which directory contains your JUnit tests.

Answer (score 2):

Go to the window menu and select favorites. Then a tab include beside projects, files...then drag a folder from file explorer and put it into favorites.

Comment: Thanks For the Help. @Mobarok

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the "Import Project" from the File menu, which can transform an Eclipse project to a Netbeans one for example (there might be other transformations available as plugins, don't know), or just create a new Netbeans project with your existing code.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to File Then New Project
2. Under "Categories" Select PHP.
3. Under "Projects" Select PHP Application with Existing Sources, Click Next.
4. Browse Source Folder and Select it.
5. Give project a name.
6. If you want you can choose PHP Version, Click Next
7. And select your Server
8. Enter project url or link. (i.e http://localhost/onlinevoting).
9. Choose index file This file is mostly index.php file or the default file for your website.
10. Click Finish.

reference : https://mauricemutetingundi.blogspot.com/2019/01/how-to-open-existing-php-project-in.html

Answer (score 0):

Just copy this template `nbproject` folder from the archive [nbproject.7z](https://gofile.io/?c=xP8m55) to your target folder. After it, you can open folder as NB project. It is just minified NetBeans 8 project definition.

[Base64 7z data uri copy](https://pastebin.com/d54mDUub)

Comment: Other variant idea is here: https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/how-to-open-any-folder-as-a-project-in-the-netbeans-platform . "Idea" is word, not IDE.

Comment: Similar answer for Eclipse: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33340070/1742529