# How to import an existing directory into Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I am on a mac, but I don't think it will make a difference. I have a directory that I want to fully import/add into Eclipse. What I did is this:

1. Right click import
2. *General → Existing Projects into Workspace*

Then when I click browse for either root directory or archive file and select the folder I can't click finish. The folder is empty and just contains a few folders but for some reason I can't click finish.

Comment: Is it actually an eclipse project that you are trying to import? Does it have the .project file in the root folder?

Comment: it is not, its just a folder created

Comment: If SVN is involved see this existing post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170963/how-to-make-an-existing-directory-into-an-eclipse-project

Answer (score 132, accepted):

The Eclipse UI is a little bit confusing.

The Import -> "Existing projects into workspace" actually means import "Existing ***Eclipse*** projects into workspace". That's why you can't click on finish: the import option looks for a `.project` file (the file used by Eclipse to store the project options) in the directory that you have chosen.

To import existing source code that doesn't have an Eclipse project file you have the following options (I suppose that you want to create a Java project):

1. **New project inside the workspace dir:** Create a new empty Java project into the workspace (File->New->Java Project). Then right click on the source folder and choose *Import...->General->File system* then choose your files, and it will make a **copy** of your files.

   **Tip:** you can drag&drop your files from the Finder into the src folder.
2. **Create an eclipse project in your existing dir:** Create a new Java project, but in the "New Java Project" window:

   - Un check the *Use default location* option, and choose the directory where is your non-Eclipse project.
   - Click *Next* and configure the sub-directories of your non-Eclipse project where the source files are located. And you are done :)

Comment: thanks im using php , what i did is create a new project and created a folder then dragged my existing folder into the created folder on the computer then in eclipse i right clicked on the folder created by magenta and clicked refresh and that did it. but its a shame that such a simple task is not an easy process.

Comment: Yes, is really complicated, I used Eclipse a lot and I feel comfortable with the shortcuts, but Eclipse needs a lot of usability improvements :( For a PHP project, you could try with Netbeans, I've used it for a small PHP project and it's easy

Comment: trick is  - `Un check the Use default location option, and choose the directory where is your non-Eclipse project.`

Answer (score 44):

There is ***no need to create a Java project*** and let unnecessary Java dependencies and libraries to cling into the project. The question is **regarding importing an existing directory into eclipse**

**Suppose** the directory is present in ***C:/harley/mydir***. What you have to do is the following:

- **Create a new project** (Right click on Project explorer, select ***New** -> Project***; from the wizard list, select ***General** -> **Project*** and click next.)
- Give to the project the **same name of your target directory** (in this case ***mydir***)
- **Uncheck *Use default location*** and **give the exact location**, for example ***C:/harley/mydir***
- Click on ***Finish***

You are done. I do it this way.

Comment: Now called General -> "Project from Folder or Archive". Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

These days, there's a better solution for importing an existing PHP project. The PDT plugin now has an option on the New PHP Project dialog just for this. So:

From File->New->PHP Project:

[image: New PHP Project Dialog with "Create project at existing location" options badly circled]

Answer (score 3):

I Using below simple way to create a project 
1- First in a directory that desire to make it project, create a .project file
with below contents:

```
<projectDescription>
    <name>Project-Name</name>
    <comment></comment>
    <projects>
    </projects>
    <buildSpec>
    </buildSpec>
    <natures>
    </natures>
</projectDescription>
```

2- Now instead of "Project-Name", write your project name, maybe current directory name

3- Now save this file to directory that desire to make that directory as project with name ".project" ( for save like this, use Notepad )

4- Now go to Eclips and open project and add your files to it.

Comment: I had a large bunch of config files in a directory...and I wanted to open all those files in eclipse...this helped a lot...awesome...

Answer (score 3):

For `Spring Tool Suite` I do:

```
File -> Open projects from File System
```

Answer (score -1):

The thing that works best for me when that happens is :

1. Create a new eclipse project(JAVA)
2. Take your source file (contents of the src folder!!!) and drag from finder and drop into the src folder in eclipse IDE
3. Make sure you add your external jars and stuff and tada you're done!!