# How to get autocomplete and project structure using Eclipse's Remote System Explorer?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

There are some projects on a linux machine I want to edit but I want to do it on my Windows machine. I can get the project to my eclipse by using the Remote System Explorer plugin > Create Remote Project. But the project is not an eclipse project, rather just listing a bunch of files. Is there a way I can create a remote project that keeps the package structures that eclipse does with normal projects? Also what about autocomplete for java code?

Answer (score 0):

When you create the project a .project file will be created in the directory you specify. This what makes the folder an Eclipse project. Afterwards you only need to import the files to your newly created project.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8611196/how-do-i-import-an-existing-directory-into-eclipse?lq=1) for detailed explanation.