# Cannot finish Installing sbteclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, github, playframework, sbt

I tried to install the sbt integration with Eclipse as the documentation said, but I'm almost sure I'm missing something. 
I created ~/.sbt/0.13/plugins/plugins.sbt with the line the github provided:
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "5.1.0")
Then, when I launched > sbt from a terminal it apparently downloaded it automatically:

Updated file /home/leandro/.sbt/0.13/plugins/project/build.properties setting sbt.version to: 0.13.15
[info] Loading project definition from /home/leandro/.sbt/0.13/plugins/project
[info] Updating {file:/home/leandro/.sbt/0.13/plugins/project/}plugins-build...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt.ivy#ivy;2.3.0-sbt-48dd0744422128446aee9ac31aa356e[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Set current project to plugins (in build file:/home/leandro/.sbt/0.13/plugins/)

However, the same readme says I should be able to run eclipse from the sbt shell to create Eclipse project files, but the shell doesn't recognizes the command.
I also don't know how use the Import Wizard to import Existing Projects into Workspace in Eclipse.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. File > Import
2. General > Existing Project into Workspace > Next
3. Browse for the project, select the one you want to import and FInish import.

or this might help 
[How do i import an existing directory into eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8611196/how-do-i-import-an-existing-directory-into-eclipse)

or just maybe use IDEA