# Eclipse how to import a web project with libraries

Tags: java, eclipse, web, import, ear

I work with Eclipse. I have in the file system a project  with the following folder structure

AR04.CME

[image]

cmeEAR is

[image]

[image]

cmeShare  is a folder with jar

[image]

[image]

cmeWeb has the structure

[image]

How do I have to import this project in the Eclipse?

Comment: _File > Open Projects from File System..._

Comment: That is a _huuuge_ question with very little content. You might want to consider some reformatting etc.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is about basic configuration/setup that is covered by the product's documentation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do i import an existing directory into eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8611196/how-do-i-import-an-existing-directory-into-eclipse)