# How to add a folder into eclipse for development work?

Tags: eclipse, git, amazon-web-services, ide

I have cloned a git repository (which contains lot of python, shell, json files) using git clone command from git bash and it is in my workspace location. I would like to add the whole repository folder into eclipse and want to do modifications / edits to the shell, python files there. How can I do it?

Note: I am Pretty new using Eclipse and I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Eclipse works with Eclipse projects, not folders. If you have a .project file then add it to your workspace, otherwise see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8611196/how-do-i-import-an-existing-directory-into-eclipse. Unless you absolutely have to use Eclipse, don't. Use a different tool, such as Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Thank you @jarmod It helped me a ton. I followed the link you have given and it works, so my question would be I could have say directory instead of folder

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to create a Java project and let unnecessary Java dependencies and libraries to cling into the project. The question is regarding importing an existing directory into eclipse

Suppose the directory is present in C:/harley/mydir

What we have to do is ,

Create a new project [Right click on Project explorer, select New -> Project, From the Wizard list, select General -> Project .. click next ]

Give the project name same as your target directory , Here 'mydir'.
Uncheck the 'Use default location' and give the exact location , ie: C:/harley/mydir and click on Finish.