# Opendaylight import to Eclipse

Tags: opendaylight

I am trying to import opendaylight source to eclipse.I have tried to import code from the git root directory but there were a lot of errors. I have followed some video tutorial on youtube to import the code but nothing worked out.

Does anyone provide me some suggestion to import the code successfully to eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

The https://github.com/vorburger/opendaylight-eclipse-setup project can help you.  If you have "previously tried that but nothing worked out", you should provide more details about what did not work for you.  Note this FAQ of that project: Q. Where can I get support if I have any further question not covered in this README?  A. For now, please post to the general OpenDaylight development list (dev@lists.opendaylight.org) with email subject topic prefix "[eclipse]".

Answer (score -1):

you can use 
https://github.com/collab-uniba/socialcde4eclipse/wiki/How-to-import-a-GitHub-project-into-Eclipse
or if it doesn't work, you can download the project zip file from github and then use "Existing Projects into Workspace"
[How to import an existing directory into Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8611196/how-to-import-an-existing-directory-into-eclipse?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)