# imported guava source code in eclipse is not runnable

Tags: java, eclipse, git, import, build-process

I need to write some Unit-Tests for google guava 15 (for an online course).
There is a semi-automatic tool involved that reads the source code and executes it with the help of eclipse. So I need readable source code (not only the binary classes) that can be run from within an unittest.

So here is what I did:

- cloned github repo via egit
- Import from git -> local repository -> general project (I tryed new java project and the new project wizard but that created empty folders, only with general project the source was at least visible within eclipse)
- went back in git history to guava version 15

But it seems that he doesn't build the java project now (of course because its a general project). I found some answers to this topic: editing the .project from eclipse to change the general to a java project but that did not work, maybe I did it wrong).

But is there an easy way to do this? Maybe by using a build tool or something? Seems to be very complicated to edit the .project for a complex project like guava, only telling him that this is a java project does not work!?

Comment: Did you check the project's build path? Check if the guava sources are available (e.g. as .jar which is the usual distribution form of guava)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This is somewhat detailed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30496367/can-i-convert-eclipse-source-folders-into-packages/30502689#30502689) answer on how to get a Maven project in Eclipse working and manage it by EGit. It describes almost the same situation.

Answer (score 1):

Guava is designed to be built using the Maven build tool.

If you want to do this within Eclipse, the M2E plugin implements Maven integration.  It knows how to import a Maven source tree as an Eclipse Java project, including setting up the ".project" file and other stuff that Eclipse needs.

Here's how to install it: [Maven in Eclipse: step by step installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8620127/maven-in-eclipse-step-by-step-installation)